# Can not send parameters to Python web service using PHP

Tags: php, python, web-services

Server:

```
import soaplib
from soaplib.core.service import rpc, DefinitionBase
from soaplib.core.model.primitive import String, Integer
from soaplib.core.server import wsgi
from soaplib.core.model.clazz import Array


class HelloWorldService(DefinitionBase):
   @soap(String,Integer,_returns=Array(String))
   def say_hello(self,name,times):
      results = []
      for i in range(0,times):
         results.append('Hello, %s'%name)
      return results

if __name__=='__main__':
   try:
        from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
        soap_application = soaplib.core.Application([HelloWorldService], 'tns')
        wsgi_application = wsgi.Application(soap_application)
        server = make_server('173.252.236.136', 7789, wsgi_application)
        server.serve_forever()
   except ImportError:
        print "Error: example server code requires Python >= 2.5"
```

PHP:

```
$client=new SoapClient("http://173.252.236.136:7789/?wsdl");
try{
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 5);
var_dump($client->say_hello("Dave", 5));
echo("<br />");
//print_r($client->add(1,2));
}catch(Exception $e){
 echo $e->__toString();
 ini_restore('default_socket_timeout');
}
```

When I run my PHP code, it reports the information below:

```
SoapFault exception: [senv:Server] range() integer end argument expected, got NoneType.     in E:\web\webservice\client.php:6 Stack trace: #0 E:\web\webservice\client.php(6): SoapClient->__call('say_hello', Array) #1 E:\web\webservice\client.php(6): SoapClient->say_hello('Dave', 5) #2 {main}
```

But it works using Python's client:

```
from suds.client import Client
hello_client = Client('http://173.252.236.136:7789/?wsdl')
result = hello_client.service.say_hello("Dave", 5)
print result
```

I found I can't send the parameters `name` and `times` to the Python server using the PHP client.

Comment: the exception says that it might need ("Dave",ARRAY) and not an integer, try changing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is, that the `soaplib` wraps the parameters and the return values in Soap-structs. You can see that if you look at the output of:

```
 var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
 var_dump($client->__getTypes());
```

So the solution is to just provide the structure:

```
class SayHelloStruct {
    function __construct($name, $times) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->times = $times;
    }
}

$struct = new SayHelloStruct("Dave", 5);
// here "say_hello" is not the method name but the name of the struct
$soapstruct = new SoapVar($struct, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "say_hello");
$param = new SoapParam($soapstruct, "say_hello");

var_dump($client->say_hello($param));
```

You can shorten that a bit by casting a hash-array to an object:

```
$struct = (object)array("name" => "Dave", "times" => 5);
// here "say_hello" is not the method name but the name of the struct
$soapstruct = new SoapVar($struct, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, "say_hello");
$param = new SoapParam($soapstruct, "say_hello");

var_dump($client->say_hello($param));
```

The `SoapParam`-thing is not ultimately required. You can omit that without breaking it.

Well I honestly don't know if there is a better solution, like some kind of flag on the server or client side.

Answer (score 1):

I had met the problem. If you want to pass the parameters to the python webservice. You just need to pass an array as the parammeter.like this:

var_dump($client->say_hello(array("name"=>"Dave","times"=>5)));